# Can I copy my mod configurations from a save to another?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

The mod configuration menu (or MCM) included in SkyUI is amazing, but it resets all mods back to default settings every time I start a new character. I have a lot of mods and I'm forced to spend maybe even an hour per character setting things up again in the MCM due to the 104 mods I have, most of which are pretty large.

Is there a way I could copy all of my mod settings from my earlier character to my new game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to import your settings from one save to another. The only mods that save their settings across saves are SKSE/other external plugins that store their configuration as .ini files.

Consider writing your settings down so you can quickly enter them again without pondering every one of them.

Comment: The issue isn't that I can't remember the settings but that there are simply so many to change, but can't do much about it, it seems :(

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could setup the settings in a very early save and then start multiple characters from that save?

I guess you might not be able to save a Skyrim save before choosing race and name? Maybe a mod would allow you to change your name and race?

Comment: This is somewhat viable because of alternative start (you start in a room where you choose your starting conditions) except when I install mods, which require a completely new game. And there's `showracemenu` console command to redo character creation.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding there is no way to transfer config files from one save to another.  What I did is installed Skyrim unbound, (an alternate start mod found on the nexus)  after the intro your in a screen overlooking Helgan from there you can set all your mods up and create a save that you'll start all new characters from. Its not a perfect solution but its worked for me just don't forget to store that save file somewhere so you can use it next time you want to playthrough the game again. Its also easy to update the configs if you update, add, or remove a mod.

Comment: An okay workaround, but if my mods change after that, it's often not safe to use that save anymore.

Comment: You get a popup saying the game may no longer work, and asks if you want to load anyway, I have over 150 mods and have gone through maybe 350 and i'm still on a stable savegame.  I think the trick is to disable mods in mcm if possible before removal. I have only had to use save game cleaner twice. so for this reason a base save is safe between different mods. unless there is a mod that is not safe between different versions and cant be cleaned? maybe don't update it? not come across any myself. I use Mod Organizer on linux.

Answer (score 1):

Start a new game. Set up all the stuff basic personal preferences with your mods after quickly making a character with no customizations. Save the game and write down the number of the file. Now, whenever you want to start a new character, open the console and type showracemenu, this lets you create your character.

Comment: Then you're restricted to never changing your load order. Most people start new games due to mod changes.